# Wordpress multisite - fallback on subsites to main site on 404 and dealing with switch_to_blog function

Tags: wp-query, multisite

## Main topic:

I have installation of wordpress using bedrock and multisite.
I want my subsites to have fallback when page doesn't exist on them and display content of existing page

Example scenario:

1. Enter `sub.example.com/test`
2. Page doesn't exist on subsite
3. Check if page exist on main site `main.example.com/test`
4. If exist, display content of this page on subsite. Everything should look like its sourced from subsite. All images etc. (function `switch_to_blog` is salt in my eye here. All links point ot main site when using this function)

## What i tried so far:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom__pre_get_posts');
function custom__pre_get_posts($query)
{
    //Get access to global variables
    global $blog_id;
    global $wp_query;
    global $using_main_site;

    if ($query->is_admin || !$query->is_main_query() || $blog_id === 1) {
        return;
    }

    $test_obj = $query->get_queried_object();

    if (!$test_obj) {
        switch_to_blog(1);
        $wp_query = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => $query->query_vars['post_type'] ?? 'page',
            'name' => $query->query_vars['name'],
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);
        //Switch back to our current site
        $using_main_site = true;
        restore_current_blog();
    }
}
```

Now i have queried my page that i want to display. But thing is, that because of function `switch_to_blog` no data can be received to actually display page and template. No images can be received etc because WP tried to operate on current sub-site.

So i tried to switch blog just after opening body. I do this after body because i want everything in my `<head>` to link to subsite and display data from subsite.

```
add_action('wp_body_open', 'xxxxx');
function xxxxx () {
    global $using_main_site;
    if($using_main_site) {
        switch_to_blog(1);
    }
}
```

In `footer.php` i do `restore_current_blog()`;